# Moving multiple images in xcode

Tags: xcode, uiimage, xcode4.2

I want to place multiple images in one xib and to move them individually.

However when I click on one of the images the other one disappears.  I don't want that.

Any

Comment: You should probably add more details to describe what you're doing and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In your View Controller

```
 #import "ImageMove.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ImageMove* imageMove = [[ImageMove alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"]];

[imageMove setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 60, [imageMove frame].size.width,[imageMove frame].size.height)];

[[self view] addSubview:imageMove];

[imageMove release];

ImageMove* imageMove1 = [[ImageMove alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feder.jpg"]];

[imageMove1 setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 200, [imageMove1 frame].size.width,[imageMove1 frame].size.height)];

[[self view] addSubview:imageMove1];

[imageMove1 release];
```

}

this is your imageView class...

```
@interface ImageMove : UIImageView {

}

@end

@implementation ImageMove


  - (id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)image 
  {
if (self = [super initWithImage:image])
  {
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 

    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
   } 

   return self;

   }


 - (void)dealloc 
 {

     [super dealloc];
  }

  - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {

if ([touches count] == 1)
{

  CGPoint newTouch = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]]; 

  CGPoint lastTouch = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView: [self superview]];

    float xDif = newTouch.x - lastTouch.x; 

    float yDif = newTouch.y - lastTouch.y;

    CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xDif, yDif);

    [self setTransform: CGAffineTransformConcat([self transform], translate)]; 

  } 


 }

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {


[self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

 }




 @end
```